# NVMe PCIe disk power cycling

Tags: linux-kernel, ssd, pci

I want to test an NVMe SSD that is connected to a PCIe slot of my motherboard.
The test procedure is a specific algorithm that writes workloads to the SSD, while the SSD is exposed to radiation (e.g., neutrons).

I am running Fedora 22, with kernel 4.4.6.

My current software successfully works with SATA SSD. Since the SSD can become unresponsive due to radiation, it's sometimes mandatory to power cycle it in order to resume operations. It is made possible with an externally controlled power supply.

Now, I would like to port my software to test NVMe SSD PCIe.
I have modified a PCIe extender to externally apply voltage to the SSD; the derived power lines (+12V and 3.3V) are isolated from the PCIe connector power lines. With this setup, the SSD is well recognized – and works – when booting with the external power supply on.

Removing the device and re-scanning the PCI bus works as long as the NVMe SSD is powered on, namely:

```
echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:01\:00.0/remove
```

followed by:

```
echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan
```

works. However, if I power-off and then power-on the device after removing it, the PCI bus `rescan` does not work (and no message appears in `dmesg`).

If I "brutally" power off the SSD (with my controlled power supply) without removing the SSD under `sysfs`, I would get the following:

```
[  192.688934] nvme 0000:01:00.0: Failed status: ffffffff, reset controller
[  192.689274] Trying to free nonexistent resource <000000000000e000-000000000000e0ff>
[  192.699900] nvme 0000:01:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
[  192.699946] Trying to free nonexistent resource <000000000000e000-000000000000e0ff>
[  192.699953] nvme 0000:01:00.0: Device failed to resume
```

And obviously, rescanning the PCI bus does nothing.

Question: what would be necessary to achieve the power-cycling of the SSD without rebooting my test station? From similar threads, I understand that this problem is not trivial, so I would be content with a wide range of solutions (or hints), including:

- Adding kernel boot parameters
- Use of `setpci` commands (hints?)
- Use of extra logic, e.g., wire modifications on the PCIe extender to "fool" the PCIe bus
- Modifications in the kernel sources (hints?)

Comment: Hot-plugging PCIe devices is discussed on electronics.SE at http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/208796 but in short, if you want to go the standards-compliant way you need to ensure both your motherboard hardware and BIOS software support hot-plug.

Comment: You may also have some luck by building your own PCIe adaptor, talking to your harddrive and proxying the communication to the motherboard, fooling it to thinking it is still alive whilst being power cycled; but I assume that would be a quite expensive work to do.

Comment: @ssice Thanks for your comments. I had already read the (very interesting) hot-plugging thread on electronics.SE. Since I was "just" power cycling the device -- and not physically removing it --, I had high hopes that my case would be simpler. Concerning the "communication" proxy, that's indeed a bit heavy a modification. I could do with pin shorting or the use a simple electronic components, though.

Comment: But even though you are not phyisically removing the device, it still needs to be re-configured again after being power-cycled, so even if you get the computer "not to notice" that the device has gone dark, you need to replay the configuration sequence so that the device is again identically configured (for the host not to notice).

Comment: Alas, the computer notices that the device has gone dark. Otherwise, I think we could just "remove" and "rescan" after the power cycle for the device to be correctly configured.

Comment: Not quite a reboot, but you could try power suspend and resume, which can be quite fast.

Comment: @meuh I had thought about it, but your remark made me search more thoroughly in this direction. It turns out that with a `rtcwake -m mem -s 5`, I can suspend for 5 seconds, and the voltage is indeed 0V on my SSD (I checked with a voltmeter). I'm using vnc to connect to the PC testing the SSD and it even turns out I do no loose the session (it just freezes for the 5 seconds). Thanks again for all the nice inputs!

Answer (score 0):

This is unlikely to succeed in getting the device to work again, but might get the device responsive enough to respond to the remove. Whilst the device is ok, save all the pci configuraton registers, and after the power-cycle restore them. You can get some way towards this by finding the controller slot

```
$ lspci | grep SATA
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
```

then listing the register names and passing each to setpci (you don't need to be root):

```
$ setpci --dumpregs |
awk -v slot='00:1f.2' 'NR>1 && !/ E?CAP/{
  reg = tolower($NF)
  printf "%s=",reg
  system("setpci -s " slot " " reg)
}'
```

This gets you lines like

```
vendor_id=8086
device_id=1e03
command=0407
status=02b0
base_address_0=0000f0b1
base_address_1=0000f0a1
base_address_2=0000f091
base_address_3=0000f081
base_address_4=0000f061
base_address_5=f7c06000
```

Obviously some of these registers are readonly, or have readonly bits. The idea is to call `sudo setpci -s "$slot"` with each of these lines, ignoring this aspect.

The above only handles the basic pci configuraton registers. However, you will need to save and restore some capability registers too. This will need more effort, depending on the register. You also need to be root to read them. For example,

```
sudo setpci -s 00:1f.2   CAP_MSI+0.l CAP_MSI+4.l CAP_MSI+8.l
```

will print the MSI capabilities registers:

```
00017005
fee0200c
000041b1
```

Compare these with the values shown by

```
sudo lspci -s "$slot" -vvv
    ...
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
            Address: fee0200c  Data: 41b1
```

Comment: Thanks for these useful insights. However, there is a major issue; when the SSD is power cycled, the SSD disappears from `/sys/bus/pci/devices`. Thus, all `setpci -s '01:00.0'` commands no longer works -- since the SSD is no longer enumerated.